# How to handle parsing where NSData contains false word?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I have NSDATA as following:

```
{"userClientToken":"ce99402d23eb33288b0cewrwer324248977","passpin":false}
```

passpin value can be false / 0 / 1.

If I parse this data into NSDictionary I get passpin as 0 for both false and 0. Is there anyway that I can get it as string like "false", "0", "1" ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  NSJSONSerialization parses `true` and `false` (without quotes) into NSNumber values.  I believe if you examine the number's objCType it will appear as Boolean, but I'm not sure of that.  The `false` value above is **not** a string, but is a Boolean value, and is essentially indistinguishable from zero.  (There's no difference in meaning between `false` and `0` in JSON.)

Answer (score -1):

It's ok for the key passpin in NSDictionary to be 0.

Deserialization is a two step process.  First you deserialize the JSON into an NSDictionary, then you use that to initialize an instance of a class using Key Value Coding setValuesForKeysWithDictionary.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property ( nonatomic, strong) NSString* userClientToken;
@property ( nonatomic, assign) BOOL passpin;

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize userClientToken, passpin;

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {
        [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
    }
}

@end
```